# Getting a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when trying to connect to Oracle via Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I am building an application using Spring MVC and Hibernate. I have not integrated Hibernate with Spring yet (new to both), and wanted to ensure a session can be opened through Hibernate first.

I created a simple function to test and currently **receiving the following error**:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.(Ljava/util/LinkedHashSet;Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/spi/ClassLoaderService;)V

My logs tell me that the error occurs when I try to use the `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings()` function call.

---

I have placed my sample function below that tries to create a connection (please note that it is void, and does not actually do anything within other than try to catch any exceptions)

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
        testHibernate();
    }
public static void testHibernate() {
        try {
            String hibernateFilePath = "src/main/java/hibernate.cfg.xml";
            File hibernateFile = new File(hibernateFilePath);
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(hibernateFile);
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

---

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle://servername.website.com:12345/dbname678</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">username</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

---

File structure for my project:

[image: File Structure]

---

**Thoughts on my approach**: I understand that the error being thrown has to do with an issue related to how the functions are called. Typically a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError occurs when function Foo of library Bar is calling version 2.0 instead of 3.0. I double checked my dependencies and tried to rebuild the project yet I still face the same issue. I also tried IntelliJ's boilerplate code for Hibernate to test connections and still receive the exact same error.

Comment: You probably have a dependency conflict; you are including version X of some library while Hibernate needs version Y. See these [instructions](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) on how to find conflicts with Maven.

Comment: @Jesper you are correct. Had some extra JAR files laying around in my lib. Removed them and now it works like a charm. Please post it as an answer so I can give you all the credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a dependency conflict, for example you have version X of some library while Hibernate needs version Y of that same library.

You can use Maven to [find dependency conflicts](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html), using a command like:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

It will print a dependency tree and indicates which libraries are in conflict with each other.